# If ibm-appid supports IBM single sign on?

Tags: ibm-appid

does ibm-appid provide the IBM single sign on(bluepages) functionality?
and how to implement/configure it? Thanks

Comment: Hello, can you be more specific about which functionality you require? What were the features you were using from Single-Sign-On? (i.e. were you using SAML? Hosting your own users?, etc...)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for IBM customer support, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not useful for non-IBM employees.

Answer (score 0):

is it about authenticating using IBMid? W3id?
If you are an IBM-ers then feel free to ping me directly.

Comment: Hi Beery, I want to authenticate using W3id, I have sent an email to you, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if AppID can authenticate using W3ID or not, but you can find good samples at https://w3-connections.ibm.com/wikis/home?lang=en-us#!/wiki/BlueID%20Single%20Sign-On%20%28SSO%29%20Self-Boarding%20Process/page/w3ID%20OIDC%20Boarding%20Instructions

I also have tried using the passport-openidconnect library for NodeJs, and the works fine too.

Comment: I know the wiki you pasted, Piyush, but I had some problems to config it, so I want to try the app_id, thank you.